# Ambient occlusion looks horrible and I don't know why

Tags: shaders, ambient-occlusion

So, I'm trying to create an AO for a model I downloaded. I'm new to Blender and want to achieve this only to embed the AO in three.js (in particular for the objects 'Edge Cut', 'Corner Cut' and 'Cube'). I tried following a tutorial, unpacking so everything is laid flat, but when I bake, shading is totally off and I have no idea why.

One thing I did notice is that the spheres at the bottom right of the shading tab are white and black instead of being white and 'venice sunset'. Not sure if it matters. Another thing I saw is that this may be related to normals, but I don't know how to navigate my way to fix these [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turned out that probably the complex model confused Blender when I tried to unwrap everything. What I ended up doing is to unwrap object by object, then select all the UV elements, average the scale and pack the islands. Then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure, but I think it has to do with the placement of your UV islands (as well as some of their shapes). As you can see from the image, the normals are all correct, so I think it *must* be UV related. I think you will need to find a way to ensure all the faces are in the 1001 space (light grey square), but not overlapping, and that all faces that need to be "even" (squared off and such) are done so accordingly. Unfortunately, it seems most (if not all) of the cubes comprising your "megacube" will need adjustment this way.

[image: NormFaces]

Also, I'm not sure if it's related, but there is a hidden object in your scene called Plane.003 - is that supposed to be there?

Comment: Any pointers on how to put faces in 1001? Will it help if I join some of them to a single mesh?

Comment: Yeah, joining it all in to one object and unwrapping it all together should definitely work. You might need to be pretty specific with seam placement, though, if you need it to unwrap a specific way. There are probably a lot better people to advise you in that area, as I'm not really up to speed on all the UV mapping "tricks". If you have issues with it, consider opening a new question that is specifically about your UV troubles. Someone better than me at this should be able to help you further.